# Align 2 :after contents below each other

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I've been experimenting with advanced selectors and it has been going great until now. I'm trying to align 2 carets below each other in a table. To make it appear like the rows are sortable. But I haven't been able to get it working and I couldn't find any information on this specific issue on google.

If anybody can help me with this or provide information, I'd appreciate it.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="table">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Column1</td>
            <td>Column2</td>
            <td>Column3</td>
            <td>Column4</td>
            <td>Column5</td>
            <td>Column6</td>
            <td>Column7</td>
            <td>Column8</td>
            <td>Column9</td>
            <td>Column10</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#table tr:first-child td:not(:nth-child(9)):not(:last-child):after {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f0d7" ' ' "\f0d8";
    float:right;
}
```

**JSFIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/jk62x5ox/

Comment: Give a smaller width to it. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jk62x5ox/2/)

Comment: @anpsmn you mean the columns? If you shrink the jsfiddle you will see that the psuedo class goes below the text. Still aligning next to each other.

Comment: @anpsmn never mind I saw your fiddle. So simple yet effective. Thanks man. Would you mind putting that in an answer so I can mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#table table {
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
#table td {
  padding: 0 5px;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
#table tr {
  background: #dbe5f1;
}
#table td:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}
#table td:last-child {
  border-right: none;
  padding-right: 0;
}
#table tr td:last-child:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f05c";
  font-size: 18px;
}
#table tr:first-child td:not(:nth-child(9)):not(:last-child):after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f0d8"' '"\f0d7";
  float: right;
  width: 5px;
  line-height: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div id="table">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Column1</td>
      <td>Column2</td>
      <td>Column3</td>
      <td>Column4</td>
      <td>Column5</td>
      <td>Column6</td>
      <td>Column7</td>
      <td>Column8</td>
      <td>Column9</td>
      <td>Column10</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```